# Derive z- or t-statistic from p-values of regression coefficients from a probit/logit model

Tags: distributions, t-test, logit, probit, z-test

I have the results from an empirical study reporting the results for a probit and logit model. They just report the p-values of the regression coefficients. I want to derive the corresponding $t$-/$z$-statistics.

Is it just the inverse of the $t$-distribution with the corresponding degrees of freedom and the given $p$-value? E.g., for the probit if $\beta_2=0.02$, $df=96$, $p=0.023$ the inverse of the $t$-distribution would be $2.31$ (using for example EXCEL's TINV(0.023;96) function).

Can I approximate the $z$-statistic in the same way if the degrees of freedom are large enough (say at least 30)? Or is there another way to get the value for the $z$-statistic from the reported results (sample size, df, and p-values)?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: For the z-statistic, do you want to calculate the z-statistic from the pvalues of the z-statistic? Or from the pvalues associated with the t-statistic? You can do either, but the two procedures are slightly different! (in a rather obvious fashion)

Comment: I want to do the second one (pvalues of the z-statistic). However, both would be interesting!

Answer (score 1):

Let $r$ be the [degrees of freedom of the residuals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom_(statistics)#Of_residuals) and $F$ be the cdf for the t-distribution. For a two-sided test:
$$ p = 2\left( 1 - F\left( \mathopen| t \mathclose|,r\right)\right) $$

Reversing this and using the fact that $b$ and $t$ will have same sign:

- If $b > 0$, then $t = F^{-1}\left(1 - \frac{p}{2} , r \right)$
- If $b < 0$, then $t = F^{-1}\left(\frac{p}{2} , r \right)$

Or equivalently:

$$ t = \mathrm{sign}(b) \cdot F^{-1}\left(1 - \frac{p}{2}, r \right) $$

In your case, the calculation would be:

$$\begin{align*} t &= F^{-1}\left(1 - \frac{.023}{2}, 96 \right) \\ &\approx 2.31 \end{align*}$$

You appear to have used the Excel function `T.INV.2T` which automatically handles the two-sided test math. Observe that:

- Excel function `T.INV(.023, 96)` returns -2.02.
- Excel function `T.INV.2T(.023, 96)` returns the correct answer of 2.31.
- Excel function `T.INV(1 - .023 / 2, 96)` returns 2.31.

To calculate the z-statistic from the pvalues of the z-statistic, you would do essentially do the same procedure but with the normal inverse CDF rather than the t inverse CDF.

Comment: You could simplify the first pair of formulas if you worked with $|t|$. The p-value for a two-tailed test is $2\, (1 - F(|t|, \nu))$. Correspondingly, $t =\text{sign}(b)\cdot F^{-1}(1-\frac{p}{2},r)$